# How do I get started training a custom voice model with Mozilla TTS on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: audio, text-to-speech, sox, mozilla-deepspeech

I'd like to create a custom voice in Mozilla TTS using audio samples I have recorded but am not sure how to get started. The Mozilla TTS project has documentation and tutorials, but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together -- it seems like there's some basic information missing that someone starting out needs to know to get going.

Some questions I have:

1. I see that there is a Docker image for Mozilla TTS, but that the documentation for it covers creating speech and doesn't mention training. Can I use the Docker image for training?
2. If I can't use the Docker image for training, how do I get a functional copy of Mozilla TTS running on my system with Python 3? I've tried following the commands that the project provides, but I get dependency errors, version conflicts, or errors about not having sufficient permission to install packages.
3. What information do I need in order to train the model? What audio formats do I need? I see that I need a `metadata.csv` file -- what do I need to put in that file? What do I customize in the config file?
4. Most of the configs reference a `scale_stats.npy` file -- how do I generate this?
5. How do I run the training?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimentation, I can share my learnings to answer my own questions.

### Can the Mozilla TTS Docker image be used for training (TL;DR: "No")

The Mozilla TTS docker image is really geared for playback and doesn't seem equipped to be used for training. At least, even when running a shell inside the container, I could not get training to work. But after figuring out what was causing PIP to be unhappy, the process of getting Mozilla TTS up and running in Ubuntu turns out to be pretty straightforward.

### Installing Mozilla TTS using Python 3, PIP, and a Virtual Environment

The documentation for Mozilla TTS doesn't mention anything about virtual environments, but IMHO it really should. Virtual environments ensure that dependencies for different Python-based applications on your machine don't conflict.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL, so Python 3 is already installed. Given that, from within my *home folder*, here are the commands I used to get a working copy of Mozilla TTS:

```sh
sudo apt-get install espeak

git clone https://github.com/mozilla/TTS mozilla-tts
python3 -m venv mozilla-tts

cd mozilla-tts
./bin/pip install -e .
```

This created a folder called `~/mozilla-tts` in my home folder that contains the Mozilla TTS code. The folder is setup as a virtual environment, which means that as long as I execute python commands via `~/mozilla-tts/bin/python` and PIP via `~/mozilla-tts/bin/pip`, Python will use only the packages that exist in that virtual environment. That eliminates the need to be root when running `pip` (since we're not affecting system-wide packages), and it ensures no package conflicts. Score!

### Prerequisites for Training a Model

For the best results when training a model, you will need:

1. Short audio recordings (at least 100) that are:

   - In 16-bit, mono PCM WAV format.
   - Between 1 and 10 seconds each.
   - Have a sample rate of 22050 Hz.
   - Have a minimum of background noise and distortion.
   - Have no long pauses of silence at the beginning, throughout the middle, and at the end.
2. A `metadata.csv` file that references each WAV file and indicates what text is spoken in the WAV file.
3. A configuration file tailored to your data set and chosen vocoder (e.g. Tacotron, WavGrad, etc).
4. A machine with a fast CPU (ideally an nVidia GPU with CUDA support and at least 12 GB of GPU RAM; you cannot effectively use CUDA if you have less than 8 GB OF GPU RAM).
5. Lots of RAM (at least 16 GB of RAM is preferable).

#### Preparing the Audio Files

If your source of audio is in a different format than WAV, you will need to use a program like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to convert the files into WAV format. You should also trim out portions of audio that are just noise, umms, ahs, and other sounds from the speaker that aren't really words you're training on.

If your source of audio isn't perfect (i.e. has some background noise), is in a different format, or happens to be a higher sample rate or different resolution (e.g. 24-bit, 32-bit, etc.), you can perform some clean-up and conversion. Here's a script that is based on an [earlier script](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/testfigures-doesnt-align/56807/25) from the Mozilla TTS Discourse forums:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import os
import subprocess
import soundfile as sf
import pyloudnorm as pyln
import sys

src = sys.argv[1]
rnn = "/PATH/TO/rnnoise_demo"

paths = Path(src).glob("**/*.wav")

for filepath in paths:
    target_filepath=Path(str(filepath).replace("original", "converted"))
    target_dir=os.path.dirname(target_filepath)

    if (str(filepath) == str(target_filepath)):
        raise ValueError("Source and target path are identical: " + str(target_filepath))

    print("From: " + str(filepath))
    print("To: " + str(target_filepath))

    # Stereo to Mono; upsample to 48000Hz
    subprocess.run(["sox", filepath, "48k.wav", "remix", "-", "rate", "48000"])
    subprocess.run(["sox", "48k.wav", "-c", "1", "-r", "48000", "-b", "16", "-e", "signed-integer", "-t", "raw", "temp.raw"]) # convert wav to raw
    subprocess.run([rnn, "temp.raw", "rnn.raw"]) # apply rnnoise
    subprocess.run(["sox", "-r", "48k", "-b", "16", "-e", "signed-integer", "rnn.raw", "-t", "wav", "rnn.wav"]) # convert raw back to wav

    subprocess.run(["mkdir", "-p", str(target_dir)])
    subprocess.run(["sox", "rnn.wav", str(target_filepath), "remix", "-", "highpass", "100", "lowpass", "7000", "rate", "22050"]) # apply high/low pass filter and change sr to 22050Hz

    data, rate = sf.read(target_filepath)

    # peak normalize audio to -1 dB
    peak_normalized_audio = pyln.normalize.peak(data, -1.0)

    # measure the loudness first
    meter = pyln.Meter(rate) # create BS.1770 meter
    loudness = meter.integrated_loudness(data)

    # loudness normalize audio to -25 dB LUFS
    loudness_normalized_audio = pyln.normalize.loudness(data, loudness, -25.0)

    sf.write(target_filepath, data=loudness_normalized_audio, samplerate=22050)

    print("")
```

To use the script above, you will need to check out and build [the RNNoise project](https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake gdb git libffi-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev

git clone https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise.git
cd rnnoise
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

You will also need SoX installed:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

And, you will need to install `pyloudnorm` via `./bin/pip`.

Then, just customize the script so that `rnn` points to the path of the `rnnoise_demo` command (after building RNNoise, you can find it in the `examples` folder). Then, run the script, passing the source path -- the folder where you have your WAV files -- as the first command line argument. **Make sure that the word "original" appears somewhere in the path. The script will automatically place the converted files in a corresponding path, with `original` changed to `converted`;** for example, if your source path is `/path/to/files/original`, the script will automatically place the converted results in `/path/to/files/converted`.

#### Preparing the Metadata

Mozilla TTS supports several different data loaders, but one of the most common is LJSpeech. To use it, we can organize our data set to follow LJSpeech conventions.

First, organize your files so that you have a structure like this:

```
- metadata.csv
- wavs/
  - audio1.wav
  - audio2.wav
  ...
  - last_audio.wav
```

The naming of the audio files doesn't appear to be significant. But, the files *must* be in a folder called `wavs`. You can use sub-folders inside `wavs` though, if so desired.

The `metadata.csv` file should be in the following format:

```
audio1|line that's spoken in the first file
audio2|line that's spoken in the second file
last_audio|line that's spoken in the last file
```

**Note that:**

- There is no header line.
- The columns are joined together with a pipe symbol (|).
- There should be one row per WAV file.
- The WAV filename is in the first column, without the `wavs/` folder prefix, and without the `.wav` suffix.
- The textual description of what's spoken in the WAV is written out in the second column, with all numbers and abbreviations spelled-out.

(I did observe that steps in the documentation for Mozilla TTS have you then shuffle the metadata file and then split it into a "training" set (`metadata_train.csv`) and "validation" set (`metadata_val.csv`), but none of the sample configs provided in the repo are actually configured to use these files. I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/issues/665) about that because it's confusing/counter-intuitive to a beginner.)

#### Preparing the `config.json` File

You need to prepare a configuration file that describes how your custom TTS will be configured. This file is used by multiple parts of Mozilla TTS when preparing for training, performing training, and generating audio from your custom TTS. Unfortunately, though this file is very important, the documentation for Mozilla TTS largely glosses over how to customize this file.

To start, create a copy of [the default Tacotron `config.json` file](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/blob/master/TTS/tts/configs/config.json) from the Mozilla repo. Then, be sure to customize at least the `audio.stats_path`, `output_path`, `phoneme_cache_path`, and `datasets.path` file.

You can customize other parameters if you so choose, but the defaults are a good place to start. For example, you can change the `run_name` to control the naming of folders containing your datasets.

**Do not change the `datasets.name` parameter (leave it set to "ljspeech"); otherwise you'll get strange errors related to an undefined dataset type.** It appears that the dataset `name` refers to the type of *data loader* used, rather than what you call your data set. Similarly, I haven't risked changing the `model` setting, since I don't yet know how that value gets used by the system.

#### Preparing `scale_stats.npy`

Most of the training configurations rely on a statistics file called `scale_stats.npy` that's generated based on the training set. You can use the `./TTS/bin/compute_statistics.py` script inside the Mozilla TTS repo to generate this file. This script requires your `config.json` file as an input, and is a good step to sanity check that everything looks good up to this point.

Here's an example of a command you can run if you are inside the Mozilla TTS folder you created at the start of this tutorial (adjust paths to fit your project):

```
./bin/python ./TTS/bin/compute_statistics.py --config_path /path/to/your/project/config.json --out_path /path/to/your/project/scale_stats.npy
```

If successful, this will generate a `scale_stats.npy` file under `/path/to/your/project/scale_stats.npy`. **Be sure that the path in the `audio.stats_path` setting of your `config.json` file matches this path.**

### Training the Model

It's now time for the moment of truth -- it's time to start training your model!

Here's an example of a command you can run to train a Tacotron model if you are inside the Mozilla TTS folder you created at the start of this tutorial (adjust paths to fit your project):

```
./bin/python ./TTS/bin/train_tacotron.py --config_path /path/to/your/project/config.json
```

This process will take several hours, if not days. If your machine supports CUDA and has it properly configured, the process will run more quickly than if you are just relying on CPU alone.

If you get any errors related to a "signal error" or "signal received", this typically indicates that your machine does not have enough memory for the operation. You can [run the training with less parallelism](https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/issues/460) but it will run much more slowly.

Comment: what is "warning: audio amplitude out of range, auto clipped." about ?

Comment: @Bira Whether it's a problem or not depends on how far along in training your TTS is. At the start of training you'll likely encounter it a lot because the TTS is producing audio that's too loud or too soft to be considered acceptable. If after a couple hundred epochs you're still seeing it, though, it could mean that your source data needs to be normalized and/or have its loudness adjusted. I have a modified version of the preprocessor script above that I'd like to post soon that adds loudness normalization -- that can help quite a bit.

Comment: how many epochs required to run to get a audible voice ? I got a "zzzz" with 1000 epochs. with my own dataset.

Comment: @GuyPaddock what tools are you using to do loudness normalization?

Comment: @Tom: I've updated the answer to include loudness normalization through pyloudnorm.

Comment: @Bira If you are doing "transfer learning" (i.e. building off of an existing model like LJSpeech"), you can get by 100,000 or so Epochs. If you are training from scratch, you need many thousands of hours of audio and it could take 500,000 or more.

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'TTS.tts.datasets' has no attribute ''` When preparing the scale_stats.npy. Do you know what I could have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note, on windows, following GuyPaddock's advice from prior, I had to use `pip install -e.` instead of leading with `./bin/pip`, and I had to use `python` instead of `python3`

Might be obvious to someone else but I am not so familiar with python or path shortcuts in shell being customized etc.

Comment: Helpful but probably would've been better as a comment. This is more about familiarity with differences in computers/platforms (Linux vs Windows) than Python. Also somewhat surprised if this is the *only* thing that needed to be changed for it to work on Windows!