# How can I run Mozilla TTS/Coqui TTS training with CUDA on a Windows system?

Tags: text-to-speech

I have a machine with a Quadro P5000 graphics card, running Windows 10. I'd like to train a TTS voice on this system. What do I need to install to make this work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's what to install/do:

1. [Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install Python 3.8 (*not* 3.9+) for Windows. During the installation, ensure that you:

- Opt to install it for all users.
- Opt to add Python to the PATH.

2. [Download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-base) and install CUDA Toolkit 10.1 (*not* 11.0+).
3. [Download](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) "cuDNN v7.6.5 (November 5th, 2019), for CUDA 10.1" (*not* cuDNN v8+), extract it, and then copy what's inside the `cuda` folder into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1`.
4. [Download](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/releases) the latest 64-bit version of eSpeak NG (no version constraints :-) ).
5. [Download](https://git-scm.com/download/win) the latest 64-bit version of Git for Windows (no version constraints :-) ).
6. Open a PowerShell prompt to a folder where you'd like to install Coqui TTS.
7. Run `git clone https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS.git`.
8. Run `cd TTS`.
9. Run `python -m venv .`.
10. Run `.\Scripts\pip install -e .`.
11. Run the following command (this differs from the command you get from [the PyTorch website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) because of [a known issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/54172)):

```
.\Scripts\pip install torch==1.8.0+cu101 torchvision==0.9.0+cu101 torchaudio===0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

12. Put the following into a script called "test_cuda.py" in the `TTS` folder:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

13. Run the script via `.\Scripts\python ./test_cuda.py` and confirm the output looks like this (the first part should have just random numbers, but the last line must read `True`; if it does not, CUDA is not installed properly):

```
tensor([[0.2141, 0.7808, 0.9298],
        [0.3107, 0.8569, 0.9562],
        [0.2878, 0.7515, 0.5547],
        [0.5007, 0.6904, 0.4136],
        [0.2443, 0.4158, 0.4245]])
True
```

14. Put the following into a script called "train.bat" in the `TTS` folder, and then customize it for your configuration file:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
set PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO=UTF-8
set PHONEMIZER_ESPEAK_PATH=C:/Program Files/eSpeak NG/espeak-ng.exe

.\Scripts\python.exe ./TTS/bin/train_tacotron.py --config_path "C:/path/to/your/config.json"
```

15. Run the script via `.\train.bat`.

If you are using a different model than Tacotron or need to pass other parameters into the training script, feel free to further customize `train.bat`.

If you are just getting started with TTS training in general, take a peek at [How do I get started training a custom voice model with Mozilla TTS on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307611/how-do-i-get-started-training-a-custom-voice-model-with-mozilla-tts-on-ubuntu-20/66307612#66307612).

Comment: If you get "UnicodeEncodeError: ‘charmap’ codec can’t encode characters in position : character maps to <undefined>" during training, you may need to apply changes from https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS/pull/394

Comment: How are you supposed to get this working on RTX cards then that are CUDA 11?

Comment: i had to additionally do `.\Scripts\pip install networkx==2.8.8` because gruut requires networkx <3 and by the given command above by default, networkx was installed in version 3

Comment: I have followed these steps very carefully, but I'm still getting False to CUDA being available. I've moved the folder as well as installed the CUDA toolkit. My GPU is a 1070 Ti if that matters. Any idea?

Comment: Any chance this could get an update? There are too many conflicting versions with packages now.

Comment: I haven't been doing anything with TTS since 2021 and I have an older card so I don't have the context for the updates, but if someone has updates to suggest (or even a video) I would be happy to update these steps.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for an updated solution, this is how I adapted GuyPaddock's instructions to run CoquiTTS training for voice cloning on Windows 11 with CUDA 11:

1. Downloaded and installed Python 3.11
2. Downloaded and installed CUDA Toolkit 11.8
3. Downloaded CUDNN v9.0.0 for CUDA 11.8, extracted, then copied folder contents into `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8`
4. Added the following to a new system variable named `CUDA_PATH`: `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8`
5. Added the following to system variable Path and a new system variable `CUDNN`:

- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8`;
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin`;
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include`;
- `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\lib\x64`;

6. Downloaded and installed the latest 64-bit version of eSpeak NG
7. Downloaded and installed the latest 64-bit version of Git for Windows
8. Opened a PowerShell prompt to a new working directory
   Ran git clone https://github.com/coqui-ai/TTS.git.
9. Ran `cd TTS`
10. Ran python -m venv .
11. Ran `.\Scripts\pip install -e .`
12. Ran the following command
    `.\Scripts\pip install torch==2.2.0+cu118 torchvision==0.17.0+cu118 torchaudio==2.2.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
13. Created script `main.py` with the following code:

```
import torch
from TTS.api import TTS

# Check if CUDA is installed
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("CUDA installed succesfully\n") 
else:
        print("CUDA not properly installed. Stopping process...")
        quit()
# Print available TTS models
view_models = input("View models? [y/n]\n")
if view_models == "y":
tts_manager = TTS().list_models()
all_models = tts_manager.list_models()
print("TTS models:\n", all_models, "\n", sep = "")

# Prompt model selection
model = input("Enter model:\n")
# for example, tts_models/multilingual/multi-dataset/xtts_v2

# Example voice cloning with selected model
tts = TTS((model), progress_bar=True).to(device)
tts.tts_to_file("This is a voice cloning test", speaker_wav="train-audio.wav",
                language="en", file_path="output.wav")
```

14. Ran the script via `.\Scripts\python ./main.py`