# How to install multiple versions of Python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Up until recently I have only worked with one version of Python and used virtual environments every now and then. Now, I am working with some libraries that require older version of Python. So, I am very confused. Could anyone please clear up some of my confusion?

1. How do I install multiple Python versions?

I initially had Python version 3.8.x but upgraded to 3.10.x last month. There is currently only that one version on my PC now.

I wanted to install one of the Python 3.8.x version and went to https://www.python.org/downloads/. It lists a lot of versions and subversions like 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 etc. etc. with 3.8.1, 3.8.2 till 3.8.13. Which one should I pick?

I actually went ahead with 3.8.12 and downloaded the Tarball on the page: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3812/

I extracted the tarball (23.6MB) and it created a folder with a setup.py file.

Is Python 3.8.12 now installed? Clicking on the `setup.py` file simply flashes the terminal for a second.

I have a few more questions. Hopefully, they won't get me downvoted. I am just confused and couldn't find proper answers for them.

2. Why does Python have such heavy dependency on the exact versions of libraries and packages etc?

For example, this question
[How can I run Mozilla TTS/Coqui TTS training with CUDA on a Windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726331/how-can-i-run-mozilla-tts-coqui-tts-training-with-cuda-on-a-windows-system). This seems very beginner unfriendly. Slightly mismatched package
version can prevent any program from running.

3. Do virtual environments copy all the files from the main Python installation to create a virtual environment and then install specific packages inside it? Isn't that a lot of wasted resources in duplication because almost all projects require there own virtual environment.

*Although related to an [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-versions-on-windows), this question is unique as it asks how to install different versions compared to the other question that addresses primarily how to run different versions*.

Comment: maybe you can use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#:~:text=Conda%20treats%20Python%20the%20same%20as%20any%20other,or%203.8%2C%20depending%20on%20which%20installer%20you%20used%3A). *Conda treats Python the same as any other package, so it is easy to manage and update multiple installations.*

Comment: Thanks @LeiYang :) I would still like to learn how to do all these Python things without Conda in case I actually have to do it myself some day.

Comment: but i don't see `without Conda` in your question, why don't you say it earlier?

Comment: @LeiYang I didn't even know what `Conda` is untill you mentioned it. :)

Comment: so, why don't you use it, like pip, it is almost a standard for python virtual environments.

Comment: There isn't really a question here about installing multiple versions, because installing multiple versions of anything is trivial - you just install one version, and repeat for each version to install. There are instead two separate questions about how to install at all, and about how to *deal with* having multiple versions. The first is a tech support question for python.org, and the second is a common duplicate.

Comment: I was going to add an answer, but since I can't, here's the summary: I use Chocolatey then `choco install python` (currently Python 3.12) and `choco install python311` to install multiple versions and then rely on `py -312` or `py -311` to invoke different versions of python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your questions depend a bit on "all the other software". For example, as @leiyang indicated, the answer will be different if you use `conda` vs just `pip` on vanilla CPython (the standard Windows Python).

I'm also going to assume you're actually on Windows, because on Linux I would recommend looking at `pyenv`. There is a `pyenv-win`, which may be worth looking into, but I don't use it myself because it doesn't play as nice if you also want `(mini)conda` environments.

**1. (a) How do I install multiple Python versions?**

Simply download the various installers and install them in sensible locations. E.g. "C:\Program Files\Python39" for Python 3.9, or some other location where you're allowed to install software.

Don't have Python add itself to the PATH though, since that'll only find the last version to do so and can really confuse things.

Also, you probably want to use virtual environments consistently, as this ties a specific project very clearly to a specific Python version, avoiding future confusion or problems.

**1. (b) "3.8.1, 3.8.2 till 3.8.13" which should I pick?**

Always pick the latest 3.x.y, so if there's a 3.8.13 for Windows, but no 3.8.14, pick that. Check if the version is actually available for your operating system, sometimes there are later versions for one OS, but not for another.

The reason is that between a verion like 3.6 and 3.7, there may be major changes that change how Python works. Generally, there will be backwards compatibility, but some changes may break how some of your packages work. However, when going up a minor version, there won't be any such breaking changes, just fixes and additions that don't get in the way of what was already there. A change from 2.x to 3.x only happens if the language itself goes through a major change, and rarely happens (and perhaps never will again, depending on who you ask).

An exception to the "no minor version change problems" is of course if you run some script that very specifically relies on something that was broken in 3.8.6, but no fixed in 3.8.7+ (as an example). However, that's very bad coding, to rely on what's broken and not fixing it later, so only go along with that if you have no other recourse. Otherwise, just the latest minor version of any version you're after.

Also: make sure you pick the correct architecture. If there's no specific requirement, just pick 64-bit, but if your script needs to interact with other installed software at the binary level, it may require you to install 32-bit Python (and 32-bit packages as well). If you have no such requirement, 64-bit allows more memory access and has some other benefits on modern computers.

**2. Why does Python have such heavy dependency on the exact versions of libraries and packages etc?**

It's not just Python, this is true for many languages. It's just more visible to the end user for Python, because you run it as an interpreted language. It's only compiled at the very last moment, on the computer it's running on.

This has the advantage that the code can run on a variety of computers and operating systems, but the downside that you need the right environment where you're running it. For people who code in languages like C++, they have to deal with this problem when they're coding, but target a much smaller number of environments (although there's still runtimes to contend with, and DirectX versions, etc.). Other languages just roll everything up into the program that's being distributed, while a Python script by itself can be tiny. It's a design choice.

There are a lot of tools to help you automate the process though and well-written packages will make the process quite painless. If you feel Python is very shakey when it comes to this, that's probable to blame on the packages or scripts you're using, not really the language. The only fault of the language is that it makes it very easy for developers to make such a mess for you and make your life hard with getting specific requirements.

Look for alternatives, but if you can't avoid using a specific script or package, once you figure out how to install or use it, document it or better yet, automate it so you don't have to think about it again.

**3. Do virtual environments copy all the files from the main Python installation to create a virtual environment and then install specific packages inside it? Isn't that a lot of wasted resources in duplication because almost all projects require there own virtual environment.**

Not *all* of them, but quite a few of them. However, you still need the original installation to be present on the system. Also, you can't pick up a virtual environment and put it somewhere else, not even on the same PC without some careful changes (often better to just recreate it).

You're right that this is a bit wasteful - but this is a difficult choice.

Either Python would be even more complicated, having to manage many different version of packages in a single environment (Java developers will be able to tell you war stories about this, with their dependency management - or wax lyrically about it, once they get it themselves).

Or you get what we have: a bit wasteful, but in the end diskspace is a lot cheaper than your time. And unlike your time, diskspace is almost infinitely expandable.

You can share virtual environments between very similar projects though, but especially if you get your code from someone else, it's best to not have to worry and just give up a few dozen MB for the project. On the upside: you can just delete a virtual environment directory and that pretty much gets rid of the whole things. Some applications like PyCharm may remember that it was once there, but other than that, that's the virtual environment gone.

Comment: Thanks Grismar. This will sound stupid but "Simply download the various installers and install them in sensible locations" does this mean I just extract the downloaded Tarball? There is an `.exe` for the latest Python version on the homepage but I couldn't find anything like that for others just a Tarball.

Comment: If there's just a tarball, that probably means there's only a newer Linux version - you should just pick the last version that has an exe for Windows. Don't worry, it just means that the changes in the latest versions don't affect Windows. It's a long answer, but please read carefully, you asked a long question (and there's a bunch of important things to learn)

Comment: Thanks Grismar. You have cleared up a lot of my doubts about Python. Just one more question. Which one should I pick from Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) and Miniconda (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)? Am I free to do anything I want with the Anaconda Individual version?

Comment: I watched a video about `pyenv-win` on YouTube and the guy was using Windows Powershell to set things up. I would like to go the most frictionless and easy route when setting up installation of multiple version for the first time.

Comment: @RealNoob pick miniconda if you want control over whats in your various environments (I prefer it for conda), pick anaconda if you just want to install a single environment and dump all your scripts in it and not worry about managing tight environments with no issues too much (it tends to be good for the scientist / engineer type that doesn't want to bother too much with programming)

Comment: The binary installers are not provided for versions in "security fixes only" stage https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3817/ So if you need the security fixes, you need to compile python yourself. (The last version with installer is 3.8.10.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Python using the windows executable installers from `python.org`. If the version is `3.x.y`, use the highest `y` that has a windows executable installer. Unless your machine is very old, use the 64-bit versions. Do *not* have them add python to your `PATH` environment variable, but *in only one* of the installs have it **install the python launcher** `py`. That will help you in using multiple versions. See e.g. [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3617292/how-to-use-pythons-py-launcher-for-windows.html).
2. Python itself does not. But some modules/libraries do. Especially those that are not purely written in Python but contain extensions written in C(++). The reason for this is that *compiling programs on ms-windows can be a real PITA*. Unlike `UNIX`-like operating systems with Linux, ms-windows doesn't come with development tools as standard. Nor does it have decent package management. Since the official Python installers are built with microsoft tools, you *need* to use those with C(++) extensions as well. Before 2015, you even had to use *exactly* the same version of the compiler that Python was built with. That is still a good idea, but no longer strictly necessary. So it is a signigicant amount of work for developers to release binary packages for each supported Python version. It is much easier for them to say "requires Python 3.x".

Answer (score 1):

Just install them. You can have any number of Python installations side by side. Unless you need to have 2 different minor versions, for example 3.10.1 and 3.10.2, there is no need to do anything special. (And if you do need that then you don't need any advice.) Just set up separate shortcuts for each one.

Remember you have to install any 3rd-party libraries you need *in each version*. To do this, navigate to the `Scripts` folder in the version you want to do the install in, and run `pip` from that folder.

Python's 3rd-party libraries are open-source and come from projects that have release schedules that don't necessarily coincide with Python's.  So they will not always have a version available that coincides with the latest version of Python.

Often you can get around this by downloading unofficial binaries from Christoph Gohlke's site. Google `Python Gohlke`.

Comment: Thanks BoarGules. :) How do I let Windows know which version of Python to run if I can't do this `Don't have Python add itself to the PATH though, since that'll only find the last version to do so and can really confuse things.` as Grismar mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it. A Python install will do that. That only matters if you invoke Python from the command line. If you need to do that then put the full path to the executable you want, as in `"c:\program files\python3x\python.exe" mycode.py`. For IDLE set up separate shortcuts, and also for PythonWin if you use that. An IDE like PyCharm lets you specify Python version per project. It is always good to know which installation is first in your `path` so you are never in doubt about what happens if you just type `python` at the command prompt instead of the full path to the executable.